# BigQuery Could not parse '\N' as datetime for field BIRTH_DATE

Tags: google-bigquery, load-csv

I want to load a CSV file into BigQuery.There are columns where the types are DATETIME, but some missing values are '\N'. So when I use the BigQuery UI  to load, got the following error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '\N' as datetime for field BIRTH_DATE (position 15) starting at location 1245
```

What's the best way to fix this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try loading as strings, and parsing in BigQuery later?

Comment: Hi Felipe, 
yes. I tried to load as strings. but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: can you give us some sample data you'd like to ingest?

Comment: 2020,MARTIN,6060,12678,\N,DEFF,\N,78000,VANICE,12,900,F,2017-09-17 13:36::21        This is one raw of that csv file

Comment: If when the DATETIME is null, \N is placed instead of a date. Why couldn't you load the column as  _string_ ?